# XPath query works fine in online XPath tester but not in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I have a piece of XML that I have to shred in SQL Server. So far I've partly succeeded but am getting no further despite looking and trying code I found online for hours...

Below the SQL code including a trimmed down piece of the XML:

```
DECLARE @xml xml, @hdoc int
SET @xml = '
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" xmlns:ns2="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310" xmlns:bg="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:zakLk01>
      <ns2:object ns1:entiteittype="ZAK" ns1:verwerkingssoort="T">
        <ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp ns1:entiteittype="ZAKOBJ" ns1:verwerkingssoort="T">
          <ns2:gerelateerde>
            <ns2:natuurlijkPersoon ns1:entiteittype="NPS" ns1:verwerkingssoort="I">
              <verblijfsadres xmlns="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310">
                <gor.openbareRuimteNaam>Westmalledreef 45</gor.openbareRuimteNaam>
                <wpl.woonplaatsNaam>B-16753</wpl.woonplaatsNaam>
              </verblijfsadres>
              <voornamen xmlns="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310">Erik</voornamen>
            </ns2:natuurlijkPersoon>
          </ns2:gerelateerde>
        </ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp>
      </ns2:object>
    </ns2:zakLk01>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument 
@hDoc OUTPUT, 
@XML,
'<root xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310"
    xmlns:bg="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310>"/>'


SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '/SOAP-ENV:Envelope') --Row Pattern
WITH 
(
Voornamen VARCHAR(50) './/ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp/ns2:gerelateerde/ns2:natuurlijkPersoon/bg:voornamen',
Adres VARCHAR(100) './/ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp/ns2:gerelateerde/ns2:natuurlijkPersoon/bg:verblijfsadres/bg:gor.openbareRuimteNaam'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc --Releasing memory
```

When I try the two XPath queries on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html using the same piece of XML they work fine and give me back the values of "voornamen" and "openbareRuimteNaam". In SQL they return NULL no matter what I try. I must be doing something wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've tried SQL Server 2014 as well as 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The reason

How is this XML generated? The problem you run into, is here:

```
<verblijfsadres xmlns="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310">
  <gor.openbareRuimteNaam>Westmalledreef 45</gor.openbareRuimteNaam>
  <wpl.woonplaatsNaam>B-16753</wpl.woonplaatsNaam>
</verblijfsadres>
<voornamen xmlns="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310">Erik</voornamen>
```

You are declaring new **default namespaces** with the same URL as you have for your other namespaces.

In the following code I removed these extra namespaces and use your code with a tiny change: No prefixes for `voornamen` and `gor.openbareRuimteNaam`. This works:

```
DECLARE @xml xml, @hdoc int
SET @xml = '
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" xmlns:ns2="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310" xmlns:bg="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:zakLk01>
      <ns2:object ns1:entiteittype="ZAK" ns1:verwerkingssoort="T">
        <ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp ns1:entiteittype="ZAKOBJ" ns1:verwerkingssoort="T">
          <ns2:gerelateerde>
            <ns2:natuurlijkPersoon ns1:entiteittype="NPS" ns1:verwerkingssoort="I">
              <verblijfsadres>
                <gor.openbareRuimteNaam>Westmalledreef 45</gor.openbareRuimteNaam>
                <wpl.woonplaatsNaam>B-16753</wpl.woonplaatsNaam>
              </verblijfsadres>
              <voornamen>Erik</voornamen>
            </ns2:natuurlijkPersoon>
          </ns2:gerelateerde>
        </ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp>
      </ns2:object>
    </ns2:zakLk01>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument 
@hDoc OUTPUT, 
@XML,
'<root xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310"
    xmlns:bg="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310>"/>'


SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '/SOAP-ENV:Envelope') --Row Pattern
WITH 
(
Voornamen VARCHAR(50) './/ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp/ns2:gerelateerde/ns2:natuurlijkPersoon/voornamen',
Adres VARCHAR(100) './/ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp/ns2:gerelateerde/ns2:natuurlijkPersoon/verblijfsadres/gor.openbareRuimteNaam'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc --Releasing memory
```

### Analyse your XML

Try your original query without the `WITH` like this

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '/SOAP-ENV:Envelope')
```

And you'll get a list, how the XML engine *sees* your elements (fragment):

```
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| natuurlijkPersoon      | ns2   | http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310 | NULL | NULL | NULL                                   |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| entiteittype           | ns1   | http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301        | NULL | NULL | NULL                                   |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| #text                  | NULL  | NULL                                    | NULL | NULL | NPS                                    |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| verwerkingssoort       | ns1   | http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301        | NULL | NULL | NULL                                   |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| #text                  | NULL  | NULL                                    | NULL | NULL | I                                      |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| verblijfsadres         | NULL  | http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310  | NULL | NULL | NULL                                   |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| xmlns                  | xmlns | NULL                                    | NULL | NULL | NULL                                   |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| #text                  | NULL  | NULL                                    | NULL | NULL | http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310 |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| gor.openbareRuimteNaam | NULL  | http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310  | NULL | NULL | NULL                                   |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| #text                  | NULL  | NULL                                    | NULL | NULL | Westmalledreef 45                      |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| wpl.woonplaatsNaam     | NULL  | http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310  | NULL | 20   | NULL                                   |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| #text                  | NULL  | NULL                                    | NULL | NULL | B-16753                                |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
| voornamen              | NULL  | http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310  | NULL | 18   | NULL                                   |
+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+------+------+----------------------------------------+
```

You can see, that the elements you are looking for, are living in a namespace, but do not have a prefix...

All this is just some explanation why your query does not work. But:

### You should use a different approach!

`FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Be as explicit as possible, so best is this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS [SOAP-ENV],
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301' AS ns1,
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310' AS ns2,
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310' AS bg
)

SELECT @xml.value('(SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns2:zakLk01/ns2:object/ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp/ns2:gerelateerde/ns2:natuurlijkPersoon/bg:voornamen/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS Voornamen
      ,@xml.value('(SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns2:zakLk01/ns2:object/ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp/ns2:gerelateerde/ns2:natuurlijkPersoon/bg:verblijfsadres/bg:gor.openbareRuimteNaam/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Adres
```

Simple and ugly is this

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//*:natuurlijkPersoon/*:voornamen/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS Voornamen
      ,@xml.value('(//*:natuurlijkPersoon/*:verblijfsadres/*:gor.openbareRuimteNaam/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Adres
```

Comment: Thank you Paweł Tajs and Shnugo! I started working with Pawełs answer and this worked out well. Without having read Shnugos answer I used the explicit full paths. I all worked out well and I have now a script that I can prepare for testing.

The XML is generated by a tool and I cannot change that. I had already noticed some namespaces in the header and others in the XML.

The FROM OPENXML was in a script I made a few years back and I decided to build from that but it is obvious now that the switch to the new method is a good one.

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.value` method instead of `OPENXML`.

Example solution:

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS [SOAP-ENV],
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301' AS ns1,
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310' AS ns2,
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310' AS bg
)

SELECT @xml.value('(//bg:voornamen/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS Voornamen,
@xml.value('(//bg:gor.openbareRuimteNaam/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Adres
```

Of course deep search `//` is not good practice. Better would be to specify every node number:

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS [SOAP-ENV],
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301' AS ns1,
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0310' AS ns2,
'http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310' AS bg
)

SELECT @xml.value('(SOAP-ENV:Envelope[1]/SOAP-ENV:Body[1]/ns2:zakLk01[1]/ns2:object[1]/ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp[1]/ns2:gerelateerde[1]/ns2:natuurlijkPersoon[1]/bg:voornamen[1]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS Voornamen,
@xml.value('(SOAP-ENV:Envelope[1]/SOAP-ENV:Body[1]/ns2:zakLk01[1]/ns2:object[1]/ns2:heeftBetrekkingOp[1]/ns2:gerelateerde[1]/ns2:natuurlijkPersoon[1]/bg:verblijfsadres[1]/bg:gor.openbareRuimteNaam[1]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Adres
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, although I'd not use the `//` (deep search) here... +1 from my side

Comment: True, I wouldn't use deep search too. It was just note about `.value` method. Even better would be to specify every node number.

Comment: True :-D ! Telling everybody *be as specific as possible* you are absolutely right .. Happy coding!